# How to get a binary parse in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have data from natural language inference corpora ([SNLI](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/), [multiNLI](http://www.nyu.edu/projects/bowman/multinli/)) that comes in this form:

```
'( ( Two ( blond women ) ) ( ( are ( hugging ( one another ) ) ) . ) )'
```

They are supposed to be a binary trees (some are not very clean).

I want to parse some of my own sentences into this format. How can I do that with NLTK or similar?

I have found the StanfordParser, but I have not been able to find how to get this kind of a parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any tree can be converted to a binary tree that preserves its constituents. Here's a simple solution that works on `nltk.Tree` input:

```
from nltk import Tree
from functools import reduce

def binarize(tree):
    """
    Recursively turn a tree into a binary tree.
    """
    if isinstance(tree, str):
        return tree
    elif len(tree) == 1:
        return binarize(tree[0])
    else:
        label = tree.label()
        return reduce(lambda x, y: Tree(label, (binarize(x), binarize(y))), tree)
```

If you want ordinary tuples instead of `Tree`, replace the last `return` statement with this:

```
return reduce(lambda x, y: (binarize(x), binarize(y)), tree)
```

Example:

```
>>> t = Tree.fromstring('''(ROOT (S (NP (NNP Oracle))
    (VP (VBD had) (VP (VBN fought) (S (VP (TO to)
      (VP (VB keep) (NP (DT the) (NNS forms))
        (PP (IN from) (S (VP (VBG being) (VP (VBN released))))))))))))''')

>>> bt = binarize(t)

>>> print(t)
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Oracle))
    (VP
      (VBD had)
      (VP
        (VBN fought)
        (S
          (VP
            (TO to)
            (VP
              (VB keep)
              (NP (DT the) (NNS forms))
              (PP (IN from) (S (VP (VBG being) (VP (VBN released))))))))))))
>>> print(bt)
(S
  Oracle
  (VP
    had
    (VP
      fought
      (VP
        to
        (VP (VP keep (NP the forms)) (PP from (VP being released)))))))
```

This will ensure binary structure, but it's not necessarily the *correct* structure. Large-coverage parsers generate non-binary branching because some attachment choices are notoriously hard. (Consider the classic "I saw the girl with the telescope"; is the PP "with the telescope" inside the object, or part of the VP?). So proceed with care.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind help, alexis.