# How to get a parse in a bracketed format (without POS tags)?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to parse a sentence to a binary parse of this form (Format used in the [SNLI](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/) corpus):

sentence:"A person on a horse jumps over a broken down airplane."

parse: ( ( ( A person ) ( on ( a horse ) ) ) ( ( jumps ( over ( a ( broken ( down airplane ) ) ) ) ) . ) )

I'm unable to find a parser which does this.

note: This question has been asked earlier([How to get a binary parse in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742809/how-to-get-a-binary-parse-in-python)). But the answers are not helpful. And I was unable to comment because I do not have the required reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code which will erase the labels for each node in the tree.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;

public class PrintTreeWithoutLabelsExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse");
    // use faster shift reduce parser
    props.setProperty("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
    props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");
    props.setProperty("parse.binaryTrees", "true");
    // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // build annotation for text
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("The red car drove on the highway.");
    // annotate the review
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      Tree sentenceConstituencyParse = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
      for (Tree subTree : sentenceConstituencyParse.subTrees()) {
        if (!subTree.isLeaf())
          subTree.setLabel(CoreLabel.wordFromString(""));
      }
      TreePrint treePrint = new TreePrint("oneline");
      treePrint.printTree(sentenceConstituencyParse);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I had some struggles getting it started. Here a short summary: download and install the [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html), save the given answer to `src/edu/stanford/nlp/examples/` and  download and export the [Stanford SRParser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.html).

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the accepted  version and as I needed something in python, I made a simple function, that creates the same results. For parsing the sentences I adapted the version found at [the referenced link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742809/how-to-get-a-binary-parse-in-python).

```
import re
import string
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
from nltk import Tree
from functools import reduce
regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))

def parse_sentence(sentence):
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'./stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27')
    sentence = regex.sub('', sentence)

    result = nlp.parse(sentence)
    result = result.replace('\n', '')
    result = re.sub(' +',' ', result)

    nlp.close() # Do not forget to close! The backend server will consume a lot memery.
    return result.encode("utf-8")

def binarize(parsed_sentence):
    sentence = sentence.replace("\n", "")

    for pattern in ["ROOT", "SINV", "NP", "S", "PP", "ADJP", "SBAR", 
                    "DT", "JJ", "NNS", "VP", "VBP", "RB"]:
        sentence = sentence.replace("({}".format(pattern), "(")

    sentence = re.sub(' +',' ', sentence)
    return sentence
```

Neither my or the accepted version deliver the same results as presented in the [SNLI](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/) or [MultiNLI](https://www.nyu.edu/projects/bowman/multinli/) corpus, as they gather two single leafs of the tree together to one. An example from the MultiNLI corpus shows

`"( ( The ( new rights ) ) ( are ( nice enough ) ) )"`,

where as booth answers here return

`'( ( ( ( The) ( new) ( rights)) ( ( are) ( ( nice) ( enough)))))'`.

I am not an expert in NLP, so I hope this does not make any difference. At least it does not for my applications.